# .net 2.0 DLL(COM interp) called by C++ in .net 4.0 environment, error is "class not register"

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I have a old version C# DLL wroten in .net 2.0 (VS2008), which export some interfaces to another C++ application(64bit). It works just fine until meet windows server 2012.

In windows server 2008, the installer use Regasm(2.0.50727 version) /codebase to register the DLL. As by default .net 3.5 is installed, all are fine.

In windows server 2012, the installer use Regasm(4.0.30319 version) /codebase to register the DLL. No error and warning, completely register success.

When call the interface from C++ application(64bit), the error is 0x80040154 (class not register).

Also if I compile the DLL code using newer VS2010 and target to .net 4.0, register it, and run C++ application(64bit), then everything is just fine.

I tried Supportedruntime, sku=xxx, useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy, etc, No one work. Is there an easy way to deal with this? A config file or something?

I do not want to have two DLL files, one for .net 3.5- and one for .net 4.0+. Or let user alway install .net 3.5 and .net 4.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: do you use regasm from frameworkx64 folder?

Comment: Yes, 64bit framework folder, I am pretty sure, I did it manually.

Comment: Is that possible to solve it just using a config file?

Comment: not sure. there could be nasty and hard-to-google things like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945701)

and what happens if you register net2.0 dll with Regasm(2.0.50727 version) on win2012?

Comment: Regasm(2.0.50727 version) is not exist on win2012 by default, if install .net framework 3.5, all then work just fine including regasm.